# Why does Arduino use USB A-B plug, instead of A to micro USB plug?

Tags: usb

I understand that A-B plug used to be common but they could have switched to micro without issues.

My questions:

- Why does Arduino use USB A-B plug, instead of A to micro USB plug?
- What are the challenged Arduino would be facing if they switched to micro USB?

Note:
By "Arduino" I'm referring to Arduino models that do not come with a micro USB port such as the most common Uno & Mega.

Comment: Are you talking about any particular Arduino?

Comment: Arduino leonardo has a micro USB. What is your question?

Comment: Just a legacy thing. Micro usb didn't even exist until april 2007.

Comment: UNO was first released in 2010 I think.

Comment: Obviously I'm referring to Arduino models that do NOT come with a micro USB here. But I will edit nonetheless. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please note that this answer is based on speculation and some common sense rather than on insider information*:

If you take look at the [hardware index](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Boards), you'll notice that significant parts of the layout (drill holes, pin spacing, and position and **type of the USB jack**) haven't changed between the *Arduino Extreme* and the current *Arduino UNO R3*), while other improvements have been made. For changes between the UNO R2 and R3, please see [Arduino UNO FAQ at adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/arduino-uno-faq) (link provided by **jfpoilpret**).

It is thus reasonable to me that keeping the USB jack was a deliberate design decision: Improve if possible, but keep the layout changes to a minimum and allow for maximum backwards compaptibility.

*But again, this is just the guess of a user!*

Comment: I am not sure, even including your comment, that it would consitute a serious answer to the question, it looks more like a lead to follow and check.

Comment: Then you should improve your answer by changing the question into something like "It is probably for backward compatibility between UNO revisions". You could even refer to https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/arduino-uno-faq#uno-r2-and-r3 which mentions backward comaptibility albeit it does not explicitly mention USB socket compatibility. Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: That makes absolute sense @KlausWarzecha, thanks! And thank you as well jfpoilpret !

Comment: Durability is also a factor. The big standard USB-B is a lot more durable than Micro-USB. Though in practice it probably doesn't make such a huge difference, you don't connect/disconnect your Arduino THAT often.
But I guess its one of the components that could die first, if you don't built a bad circuit with your UNO, the connector could indeed die first after years and years of usage.